# Bag 3 identification help!

Tags: set-identification

I have bag #3 with 539R7 underneath it. The plastic bag has 135149 which indicates it’s from 2011. The bag has red, black, and dark grey pieces along with 6 wheels.

Any help would be appreciated.
[image][image]

Comment: Could you add a picture of the bag?

Comment: The printing and barcodes on the bag are a Lego Stock Keeping Unit that identifies the type of bag used. Think of it like the barcode on a reusable grocery bag. The code lets you know the kind of bag it is but not what groceries are in the bag.

Comment: I’ll post one in the morning, thanks.

Comment: @Dan1138 I guess these barcodes actually tell TLG what is inside. It is easier to identify content by code rather than included parts. Only downside - database for these codes is private and, due to lack of access to it, numbers found on bags are useless for community.

Comment: I added pics, hopefully this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to BrickLink, [60183 Heavy Cargo Transport](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=60183-1) seems to be the only set that has all of

- [Red 4 x 6 plate](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3032&colorID=5&in=A)
- [White Tile, Round 2 x 2 with Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=18674&colorID=1&in=A)
- [Tile, Round 2 x 2 with Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=93274&colorID=5&in=A)

Comment: Other pieces seem to match. I'd thought the 4 x 4 round plates were LtBley (for sure the one near the bottom), but the inventory shows only DkBley.